# Blender restart comput

Tags: error

Blender restart my computer.
I work (just modelling), and for no reason the mouse freeze, and the computer restart !
I try to shutdown 2 addon (camera rig and fSpy).
But the problem still there.
And it's not the first time...and can't work

**CPU:** Intel Core i7-6820HK
**RAM:** 32 Go
**GFX:** nVidia Geforce 1070, 256MB
**OS:** Windows 10, 64bits (the driver is update)
**Blender:** 2.79b Date:2018-03-22 14:10 Hash:f4dc9f9d68b

Thanks for your help !

Comment: does it happen after opening blender

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to tell for sure without an error log, but there is no reason Blender should directly send a signal for the computer to shutdown. It sounds like for some reason Blender started taxing the system immensely, causing some other system to prompt a shutdown, or some of your hardware is not working well with Blender. A common issue for this sort of thing is a driver conflict. Keeping your drivers up to date is a good idea, but it may not always fix conflicts. There are so many combinations of things that could have gone wrong that it is impossible to help you more without a precise error log, and even then it may be impossible.

My advice is to try recreating the situation when the crash occurred and see what happens. Then check the system and Blender log files.